# translating the word and picture from Chinese to english

Tags: translation

[image]
can you guys please help me translate the meaning of this picture and words
does it mean 1. like the kind you want to marry(refering to the person in the picture) or 2. like the type that likes to marry you (meaning she likes someone who wants to marry her) thank you

Comment: I like you. Like the kind of like which makes me want to marry you.

Comment: i dont understand it is it 1 or 2 ?

Comment: The context is vague here. I would guess it tries to say "I like you. My liking to you is the kind of like which makes me want to marry you."

Answer (score 1):

喜欢
I am fond of you
（心脏）
(pulls on my heart strings)
就是
that is
想嫁给你的
want-to-marry-you
那种喜欢。
that kind of fondness.

(Romantic music tinkles in the background, advertisements for diamond rings appear. In the next scene, they are in Las Vegas. My advice: if she doesn't say 'I love you' directly, she probably doesn't. She is beating around the bush.)

Comment: Should be 爱心 here not 心脏 *cringe*

Comment: I agree on the point "*She is beating around the bush*". She could be just testing the guys around her. OP could be one of them. I would think getting a direct answer from her is better than guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add punctuation to the sentence so you can understand more easily.

" '喜欢'-- 就是 '想嫁给你' 的那种喜欢."

" 'Like',  is 'I want to marry you' that kind of like."

> *Better English phrasing would be: " When I said 'Like', It meant 'I wanted to marry you', that kind of like."*

- The first '喜欢' is the topic.
- 就是 '想嫁给你' 那种喜欢 is the comment (clarification) of the topic

She was clarifying what degree of 'like' she was talking about. Apparently, She likes you to the point of wanting to marry you.

Comment: so is she refering to the type of like or the kind of person? she would like?

Comment: basically what im asking is does she like another person or she is just saying i should like her like im going to marry her?

Comment: See my edition at the bottom.

Comment: who another person or me? i dont get it? im not joking this girl looks like angela baby i just got back to her after no contact rule

Comment: The character 嫁 is to describe female marrying male.

Comment: yeah so what does this mean? is there another guy in the picture or is she testing me?

Comment: The subject is '你' --You. Although she didn't write " 当我说 '我喜欢你' , 那 '喜欢' 就是 '想嫁给你' 的那种喜欢."

Comment: Then perhaps you should as her than us here. That sentence misses subject. I don't know it's "I like you" or "You like me" or "He likes me" or "It like it" because it's just "like". The object is "you" though. However I don't know the "you" here means literally you or another GUY. 嫁 is specifically used as a woman marries a man.

Comment: so she wants to marry me? i just cameback and she was all sad and everything until today when i came back...pls im Chinese also but 我是华人所以我的中文没呢美好。你的意思是她想结婚跟我了吗？

Comment: She didn't say she wanted to marry you. She just said she like you to the degree of **wanting to marry** you." Similar to I said " I like airplane to the point of wanting to buy one."

Comment: i think Tang Hos comments were helpful.the subject is 你 i know i think its me because she is really shy in expressing herself she stated this even before and all my friends said China girls are so shy to express there feelings.she posted this today after i cameback so i think this is meant for me

Comment: It meant, if you ask her to marry you, she would seriously consider saying yes if the circumstance permit. There are a lot to consider before one can commit to a marriage.